# Continuous integration Xcode altool Error: Exception while launching iTunesTransporter

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-server

If anyone is using altool to automate uploads for continuous integration I believe they broke it at 6.3.x.

```
altool[] *** Error: Exception while launching iTunesTransporter: Transporter not found at path: /usr/local/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter.  You should reinstall the application.
```

Answer (score 12):

My fix for now was just to locate and link the location.

```
ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/itms /usr/local/itms
```